# Valgrind and GDB on same roslaunch File

Tags: ros, c++, roslaunch, gdb

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Folks,

How can I launch both valgrind and gdb on the same launch file? It seems that I can only add one "launch-prefix" attribute on my lunch file.
This is what I tried:

```
launch-prefix="valgrind --vgdb=yes --vgdb-error=0" launch-prefix="xterm -e gdb --args set non-stop off target remote | vgdb run"
```

but I get that "duplicate attribute" error.

Or is there another way to look for **ALL** possible errors that can be happening in my program? Can GDB be enough to catch all the program errors, including memory leaks?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245082/valgrind-and-gdb-on-same-roslaunch-file/) by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 803 on 2016-10-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-06**:
I don't think this kind of combination was considered when `launch-prefix` was designed and implemented. `vgdb` support in Vagrind is relatively new (~2014?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think it would be possible to use the `launch-prefix` route to get what you want. For `vgdb` to work, your node needs to be loaded into Valgrind, which will then start its own `gdb` server. The `gdb` session would then connect to that server. `launch-prefix` just takes the full path to the node `roslaunch` would normally start, prefixes it with your set prefix (ie: `gdb ..`), appends some parameters and the starts the entire command.

In your case it would seem Valgrind should be started with your node, with `gdb` connecting after that. Problem is that `launch-prefix` does not support that scenario. Valgrind could perhaps run in the background, but that is not how `launch-prefix` is supposed to work.

A work-around (for now, until someone comes up with a better way) could be to not launch your node through a launch file, but separately from the command line. The rest of your system could still be configured and setup using a launch file of course.

Another approach which might work is to use a wrapper bash script. That script would take care of starting Valgrind and `gdb`, and you'd use the wrapper script as a `launch-prefix`. That would allow you to start your entire system using a launch file. But without starting Valgrind as a background task, I'm not sure how this is going to be different.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0